# NoClassDefFoundError on ActivityCompat while unittesting

Tags: android, junit4

I'm trying to use JUnit4, PowerMock for unit testing my Kotlin code in my Android Project and these not instrumentation test cases but plain JUnit test cases. When I run test case, I always error below. Can someone please help to resolve the error, Im not sure if Im missing some dependencies.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat
```

My Gradle depencies are :

build.gradle:

```
deps.junit          = "junit:junit:4.12"
deps.mockito        = "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22"
deps.android_mockito= "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22"
deps.powermock     = "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0"
deps.powermock_junit = "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0"
```

app/build.gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
testImplementation deps.mockito
testImplementation deps.powermock_junit
androidTestImplementation deps.powermock
androidTestImplementation deps.powermock_junit
```

I have bunch of static methods so using PowerMock

Comment: Can you post where it crashes? Or at least the full logcat? And class which is failing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any Android class in your tests the test must be placed into **androidTest** folder. For purely unit testing you can use test **folder**.

Comment: Im making a library project, that does not have any UX. So using JUnit, is there a way I can use any mockable Android jar

Comment: There is some dependence of Android on your project because the error is concrete "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android / support / v4 / app / ActivityCompat"
Can you paste the code?